# Questions about dark energy and negative pressure

Tags: cosmology, pressure, dark-energy

The existence of dark energy leads negative pressure. Is the pressure can be anisotropic? What situation can cause anisotropy of pressure? Further, Is the pressure can be negative in some directions and be positive in other directions? Such as in spherical coordinates, the radial pressure is negative and the tangential pressure is positive. Will this happen when matter and Dark energy exist at the same time?

Comment: The energy-momentum tensor for dark energy is proportional to the metric tensor. I think this means that its negative pressure is isotropic.